# Pandas dataframe, duplicate rows values for each step

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate-functions

I want to duplicate rows in a Pandas dataframe. Each row should be repeated n times, where n is a number of columns from step1 to stepN.
What I have:

```
import pandas as pd        
pd.DataFrame(data={
      'id': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
      'n' : [  1,   2,   3],
      'step1' : [ '10rs',  '13rs',   '8rs'],
      'step2' : [ '100rs',  '130rs',   '8rs'],
      'step3' : [ '1000rs',  '1rs',   '8rs'],
      'step4' : [ '1rs',  '3rs',   '8rs']
    })

    id  n   step1   step2   step3   step4
0   A   1   10rs    100rs   1000rs  1rs
1   B   2   13rs    130rs   1rs     3rs
2   C   3   8rs      8rs    8rs     8rs
```

what I want in return:

```
pd.DataFrame(data={
  'id': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B','B','B','C','C','C','C'],
  'n' : [1  ,  1   , 1  , 1,  2  ,  2 , 2  ,2 , 3,3 ,3, 3  ],
  'step' : [ 10,  13,  13,   1,   13, 130 , 1, 1, 8 ,8 ,8 ,8 ]})

    id  n   step
0   A   1   10
1   A   1   13
2   A   1   13
3   A   1   1
4   B   2   13
5   B   2   130
6   B   2   1
7   B   2   1
8   C   3   8
9   C   3   8
10  C   3   8
11  C   3   8
```

I tried `pd.pivot` but too many steps to reach to final stage
Is this possible?

Comment: My Bad , here user1 is A, user2 is B and User3 is C

Comment: Please edit the question and add proper description

Comment: @PuneetSinha , is this solution working for your case ?

Comment: @PuneetSinha - Sorry, can you explain more `Each row should be repeated n times, where n is a number of columns from step1 to stepN.` ?

Comment: @NagaKiran I will surely check and comment back.. in like 4-5 hours ... caught up with some other task .. i will defiantly reach out , for help if needed... and i really appreciate your quick reply

Comment: @jezrael ... consider it like you have tasks  which can include some steps ... like if task is to book a flight ticket , so steps will be login to travel website,select src abs dest, pay,review etc, so say it had 5 steps involved now next day you did a task which involved 10 steps.... so i want your other attributes as it is and just each step will be in a row , which currently one row is one task.

Comment: @PuneetSinha - yes, but my problem is not understand output data - are  correct? Why for User `A` is `10,13,13,1` ?

Comment: yes it should be 10,100,100,1 for User A

Comment: @all Now I have edited the question for people to solve it better and for future use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try of renaming all step columns names as unique and `stack` the dataframe

```
what_i_have.rename(columns=lambda x: 'step' if 'step' in x else x,inplace=True)
what_i_have.set_index(['id','n']).stack().reset_index()
```

Out:

```
    id      n   level_2  0
0   user1   1   step    10rs
1   user1   1   step    100rs
2   user1   1   step    1000rs
3   user1   1   step    1rs
4   user2   2   step    13rs
5   user2   2   step    130rs
6   user2   2   step    1rs
7   user2   2   step    3
8   user3   3   step    8rs
9   user3   3   step    8rs
10  user3   3   step    8rs
11  user3   3   step    8rs
```